# No such device error in opencv

Tags: opencv, camera, usb

Guys i am using a code segment to detect red color with camera and at the same time taking data with sensonrs in multithread. After a while I am getting "No Such Device" error and camera and all usb devices such as mouse and keyboard are frozing. Is there any idea what is the source of this error?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, caused by xhci usb (high speed usb) driver disabling my internal usb hub. It occurred each time I've run an OpenCV based application and crash it / kill it. This caused timeout of xci usb driver, which could be seen in dmesg.

The only solution I found was to build a custom kernel for my Kubuntu Linux, which included high-speed usb driver as a module, instead of having it compiled into the kernel.
I've used [this wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/BuildYourOwnKernel) to set-up kernel building environment, and changed xhciusb module from *(compiled into kernel) to M(module plugged into kernel at runtime).

Comment: Can you give more detail please? I am using raspberry for my code how can i solve the problem step by step?